# Accessing User Defined Fields in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, user-defined-fields

So, I have a custom email form/message like below and I want to access the "Doc Title:" field value to insert it into the body of the email.

I currently have this code;

```
Function Item_Send()
    Item.Body = Item.Body + UserProperties.Find("TextBox1").Text
End Function
```

And I've tried multiple variations of this, such as `Item.UserProperties.Find(...).Value`, `Find(...).Value` by itself, `UserProperties.Find("TextBox1", false).Text`, etc.

Research;
[CodeProject](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/427913/Using-User-Defined-Fields-in-Outlook&ei=UXOVUeSGOISUiQfDrYHIDw&usg=AFQjCNFBs-qLHqOZ0MTeNOv0efZjYhwNiA&sig2=iJy7OIi4YYfSU14NOC3zhg&bvm=bv.46471029,d.aGc&cad=rja)
[MSDN Find Method Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863689.aspx)
[Microsoft Support - How to create an email message form](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258256)
[Microsoft Support - FAQ about custom outlook forms](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146636)
[Microsfot Support - Working with User Defined Fields](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185050)

I just can't seem to find a solution.
The posted code returns `Object requred: 'UserProperties.Find(...)'`
If I add in `false` to the parameters I get; `Object doesn't support this property of method: 'UserProperties.Find'`
Find by itself gives me `Type mismatch: 'Find'`

And that's all the error messages I can get to come up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I'm using the Script Editor button to write the above code, not the Visual Basic button).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You never check that `UserProperties.Find` returns null. Change the problematic line to

```
set prop = Item.UserProperties.Find("TextBox1")
if Not (prop Is Nothing) Then
  Item.Body = Item.Body + prop.Value
End If
```

Also make sure the property name is really "TextBox1", that sounds like a control name. Have a look at the item with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) (I am its author): click Item button, select the UserProperties property, click browse, go to the IEnumVariant tab, double click on the property.

You can also click the IMessage button to see the raw MAPI properties.