# Extract value from Outlook email message custom field, and populate Excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I have designed an Outlook email form that holds several custom fields. One is "reference number", a free text box with the name "TextBox1":
[image]

I am trying to display the contents of that text box so I can later populate Excel, using this as a first step just to display the contents (doesn't work)...

```
    MsgBox (msg.UserProperties.Find("TextBox1", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText).Value)
```

Can anyone correct this line for me please? I want the message box to display "1234567".
Once I get that right, I can then copy the value into the Excel sheet.

Many thanks for your time.

Shane
(Wetherby, UK).

EDIT:
Here is more complete code showing the declaration and assignment of objects:

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim nmspace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object

Set nmspace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folder = nmspace.PickFolder

'Look at each email message in a folder
For Each item In folder.Items
    intColumnCounter = 1
    Set msg = item
    intRowCounter = intRowCounter + 1
    Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
    rng.Value = msg.To
```

...more items here to pick up sender address, subject, date sent, etc)...

```
    MsgBox (msg.UserProperties.Find("TextBox1", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText).Value)
    'This is the field whose value I want to take for Excel
Next item
```

SECOND EDIT:
Here is a screen grab of the object's advanced properties:

[image]

It is a "normal" free text box entered into an email template. It's got the right name (TextBox1), and even has the right value (1234567). But somehow I cannot get the code to read the value of 1234567 and display it in the message box.
I'm stumped. it needs someone clever than me! Thank you to all who are pondering this one.

Comment: Does your reference `msg` works? What error does it give you?

Comment: @R3uK I think so. It is defined by:
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
The error message on the MsgBox line is:
`Run-time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set.`
I suspect "UserProperties.Find" is not the correct command to use here.

Comment: Okay but did you set the variable? I mean `Set msg = ....`
Can you add the start of your code? right until the `Msgbox`, because the error is more consistent with this missing declaration

Comment: That error suggests that the `msg.UserProperties.Find` method is returning a `Nothing` instead of an object (e.g., TextBox1). See this similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599607/accessing-user-defined-fields-in-outlook  and make sure the name of the *property* is actually `TextBox1` (which looks like it's a control name, not necessarily the property name.

Comment: To R3uK and David Zemens - thank you both for your help here. I was indeed using the incorrect identifier in my code. I've edited the entry to show where I was going wrong. Onward and upward. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!!!** (Apologies for shouting).
Earlier replies got me thinking. I tried this line instead:

```
MsgBox (msg.UserProperties.Find("New - Study Number").Value)
```

as "New-Study Number" is what was used for the field name:

[image]

I think part of my problem was I was getting confused with the various usages (property name, field name, control name) and the VBA field properties boxes being a little unclear.
Nevertheless - thank you to all who contributed; I hope this helps others! 8)