# Unable to read outlook custom form through python

Tags: python, vba, outlook, outlook-form

I have an outlook email which is a custom-form. It opens as a form when we double click on it. If we open it as a normal mail(single-click) it opens with some default body signature.
I am able to read normal mails. 
I need the process of how to read the outlook custom-forms

I tried with the following code where it could read the forms.

```py
import win32com.client
import win32com

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts= win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts;
folders_object = outlook.Folders(accounts[0].DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
inbox = folders_object.Folders(2)
print inbox
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
while message:
    print message.body
    message = messages.GetPrevious()
```

I am expecting to get the form data. But I am getting only a plain email. The form can be opened by double-clicking. 
Need some suggestion to read the outlook custom form through python.

Comment: I think the "outlook-restapi" tag is not correct, as this is the COM API.

Comment: Generally the objectmodel is the same as used in VBA, so this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/30171344/5950790

Comment: Yes this worked

Answer (score 1):

I am able to extract details from the custom form as:

```py
message.UserProperties.Find('property_name')
```